# Problems in displaying polyphonic Chinese characters

Tags: flutter, dart, cjk, pinyin, bopomofo

I attempted to display polyphonic Chinese characters in Dart using the BpmfIansui-Regular.ttf font, which is designed for traditional Chinese characters with BoPoMoFo annotations. For instance, the tone of the Chinese character '一' (one) varies depending on the tone of the subsequent character. If the following character carries the fourth tone, as seen in '看一看' ('kàn yī kàn'), then '一' shifts to the second tone. Conversely, if the next character is in the first, second, or third tone, '一' retains the fourth tone, as in '寫一寫' ('xiě yī xiě'). The BpmfIansui-Regular.ttf font functions effectively in applications like Word and PowerPoint.

I used the following code, but it still shows "一" in the first tone (the default). It should display

```
Text(
    '\u{7528}\u{4E00}\u{E01E1}\u{7528}', // Unicode for 用一用, u{4E00}\u{E01E1} for "一"
    style: TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'BpmfIansui-Regular',
      fontSize: 40,
    ),
 ),
```

Comment: This is something a font does based on whether or not the font _engine_ understands how to do that, so: which font engine does Dart use, and have you looked at how to make sure it's applying the correct OpenType script, features, and lookups? (which are the three things that determine the GPOS and GSUB behaviour of a font)

Comment: Mike, Thanks for the good questions. Being new to Dart/Flutter, I don't know where to look for the answers to your questions. I do know that BpmfIansui-Regular.ttf supports polyphonic Traditional Chinese characters and is used quite extensively in Taiwan.

Comment: I found out how to do it. In the FontFeature class, one can set stylistic set. See the following example. For details, see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FontFeature-class.html

            Text('Raleway Dots',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFeatures: <FontFeature>[FontFeature.stylisticSet(1)],
                  fontFamily: 'Raleway Dots',
                  fontSize: 48,
                )),

Comment: Don't post that as a comment, post it as an answer =)